# Looping tasks in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, uri

I have the following tasks in Ansible:

```
- name: Getting Job Info
  uri:
     url: "https://{{ hostname }}/job/JobService"
     method: POST
     user: "{{ username }}"
     password: "{{ password }}"
     body: "{{ lookup( 'template' , 'jobInfo.xml.j2' )  }}"
     status_code: 200
     validate_certs: false
     headers:
       soapaction: "getJobInfoVO"
     return_content: true
  register: job_status_soap

- name: Converting Job Info response to JSON
  set_fact:
    job_status_json: "{{ job_status_soap.content | xml2json }}"

- name: Setting Job Status
  set_fact:
    job_status: "{{ job_status_json['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['multiRef'][0]['status']['#text'] }}"

- debug: msg="{{ job_status }}"
```

As you can see, it makes a web service call, converts the SOAP response to JSON and then extracts the relevant value (an integer) and sets it as a fact. I need to repeat this block of code until the aforementioned integer value is equal to certain integer.

Any ideas on how I might approach this task?

Comment: Can you generate a list of the integers?  Then you could use it as a dict, and loop through using with_items?

Answer (score 0):

This would have been easy to implement using `until` to execute ansible [do-until loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) if the response was in JSON format.
But here's a working example with xml response.

Pre-requisites: (Make sure you have the python dependencies installed on your ansible host)

1) Using custom [xml_to_json](https://github.com/nasgoncalves/ansible-xml-to-json-filter) filter.

2) Using [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter

P.S. Executing following play will not trigger retry as the `until` contion is already met.
If you want to test if retry is working then change the `until` condition or the value of  tag in the request header.

```
---
- name: Retry url until xml content equals certain value
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become_user: root
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Check job status
      uri:
          url: "https://httpbin.org/anything"
          method: GET
          timeout: 10
          validate_certs: no
          headers:
            content: "<envelope><body><request><status>2</status></request></body></envelope>"
      register: get_search_job_status_response
      until: get_search_job_status_response.json.headers.Content|from_xml|json_query('envelope.body.request.status')|int == 2
      retries: 2
      delay: 2
...
```